# Dynamically Add Vus.js components in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs2

I have an ASP.NET Core project and would like to use vue.js for it's templates.

On my page I would like to display a list of items:

```
<div>
    <img :src="" .... />
   <p>{{mytext}}</p>
</div>
```

When a user clicks show more, I want to display 8 more items at a time.  How can I do this?  Does someone have an example of how to do this with a for loop that is updated with data from an ajax call?

Comment: Include Vue in your template and initialize Vue in JavaScript. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: docs for v-for https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html